# How to get instant video playing from url in android without any delay after being swiped to

Tags: java, android, instagram, android-videoview, exoplayer

I'm trying to make a short video app in android with java. Everything is working fine but after swipe new video takes 1 or 2 seconds to play the video. I want to play the videos instantly like Instagram reels or YouTube shorts. I have tried videoview and exoplayer both but didn't get result that I am expecting.

Expecting pause less video play on every swipe.

> ```
> public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>     List<VideoItem> videoItems = new ArrayList<>();
>     public static ExoPlayer player ;
>     private String my_id="123";
>     private String videoURL,userid,username,videoDescription,postid,like_count,dislike_count;
>     private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
>     ViewPager2 videosViewPager;
>     MediaItem item;
>
>
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
>         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
>         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
>         getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
>         getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>         videosViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVideos);
>         mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
>         sendshorts();
>         player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
>         
>         player.setRepeatMode(player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
>
>         videosViewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
>             @Override
>             public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
>                 super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onPageSelected(int position) {
>                 super.onPageSelected(position);
>                 Log.d("satyam","current position"+position);
>                 player.seekTo(position,1);
>                 player.play();
>
>             }
>
>             @Override
>             public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
>                 super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
>
>             }
>         });
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onDestroy() {
>         player.release();
>         super.onDestroy();
>     }
>
>
>     public void sendshorts() {
>
>         String url = "myurl";
>         Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
>         params.put("my_id", my_id);
>         params.put("url"," " );
>         final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(params);
>         JsonObjectRequest jsonObject = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
>           
>                 try {
>                   
>                     JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("videosend");
>                     for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
>
>                         JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);
>                         videoURL = jsonObject.getString("videoURL");
>
>                         userid = jsonObject.getString("user");
>                     
>
>                         username = jsonObject.getString("name");
>                         
>
>                         videoDescription = jsonObject.getString("videoDescription");
>                         
>
>                         postid = jsonObject.getString("postid");
>                     
>
>                         like_count = jsonObject.getString("like_count");
>                        
>
>                         dislike_count = jsonObject.getString("dislike_count");
>                         
>
>
>
>
>                         VideoItem v = new VideoItem(videoURL,username,videoDescription,userid,postid,like_count,dislike_count);
>                         videoItems.add(v);
>                         item=MediaItem.fromUri(videoURL);
>                         player.addMediaItem(item);
>                         player.prepare();
>                     }
>
>                     videosViewPager.setAdapter(new VideosAdapter(videoItems));
>
>
>                 }catch (Exception ignored){
>                 }
>             }
>         }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
>                
>             }
>         });
>         mRequestQueue.add(jsonObject);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onPause() {
>         super.onPause();
>     }
> }
> ```

and my adapter is

```
public class VideosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideosAdapter.VideoViewHolder>{
    private static View iv;
    private List<VideoItem> mVideoItems;



    public VideosAdapter(List<VideoItem> videoItems) {
        mVideoItems = videoItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull VideoViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull VideoViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder);

        MainActivity.player.setVideoTextureView(holder.styledPlayerView);
        MainActivity.player.play();

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new VideoViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_videos_container,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VideoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setVideoData(mVideoItems.get(position));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mVideoItems.size();
    }

    class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtTitle,txtDesc;
        ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        TextureView styledPlayerView;
        public VideoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            styledPlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);

        }
        void setVideoData(VideoItem videoItem){
            txtTitle.setText(videoItem.username);
            txtDesc.setText(videoItem.videoDescription);
        }
    }
}
```

After swipe up or down videos are taking one or two seconds to play. I want to play it instantly like reels or shorts.